# I cannot write in my Searchfield, but the Suggestion-Function works. How can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

i have a wierd problem with my searchField in my SAPUI5 Application.
I cannot write something in my Inputfield but the Search suggest me some Ordernumbers? Maybe someone can help me - thanks a lot!

View:

```
    <SearchField id="orderSearchField" value="{Ordernr}" placeholder="Vertragsnummer suchen..." enableSuggestions="true" search="onSearch"
                                suggest="handleSuggest" showSearchButton="false" suggestionItems="{ path: '/OrderSet', length: 10, sorter: { path: 'Ordernr' } }"
                                liveChange="handleOrderChange">
                                <suggestionItems>
                                    <SuggestionItem text="{Ordernr}" description="{Name1} {Name2}" key="{Ordernr}"/>
                                </suggestionItems>
                            </SearchField>
```

Controller:

```
    handleSuggest: function (oEvent) {
        var sTerm = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue"),
            oSearchField = oEvent.getSource(),
            oBinding = oSearchField.getBinding("suggestionItems");
        var aFilters = [];
        if (sTerm.length > 0) {
    
            aFilters.push(
                new sap.ui.model.Filter(oSearchField.data("prop"), sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.StartsWith, sTerm));
            aFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Status", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 5));
            oBinding.filter(aFilters);
            oBinding.attachEventOnce("dataReceived", function (oEvent) {
                oSearchField.suggest();
            });
        }

    onSearch: function (event) {
        var oSource = event.getSource(),
            oItem = event.getParameter("suggestionItem");
        if (oItem) {
            var objectPath = oItem.getBindingContext().getPath(),
                oView = this.getView(),
                sPath = oView.getBindingContext().getPath();
            this._setOrderData(objectPath, sPath);
        }
    },

    handleOrderChange: function () {
        this._resetOrderData();
    },
```

Comment: Everytime you press a Key `handleOrderChange` gets called which calls `this._resetOrderData`. This probably resets your OrderModel. Your Searchfield value is bind to your *Ordernr*. So everytime you press a Key your Searchfield will be reseted ?! Code Snippet of `_resetOrderData` would help.

Comment: Thanks a lot - That helped me!